# How can I use a proxy on AVD?

Tags: android, proxy, android-virtual-device

I have tested different types of proxy on the android AVD (SOCKS5 and http) and it says "succefully connected" But when trying to search something on google it says "This site cant be reached, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) server IP address could not be found".

I have try using different proxys and I expect to let me search on google.